# Checking the referrer

Tags: javascript, referrer

I'm using this to check if someone came from Reddit, however it doesn't work.

```
var ref = document.referrer;
if(ref.match("/http://(www.)?reddit.com(/)?(.*)?/gi"){
    alert('You came from Reddit');
} else {
    alert('No you didn\'t');
}
```

Suggestions on the regular expression are most welcome too.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?reddit\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
  alert("Came from reddit");
}
```

The regexp:

```bash
/^           # ensure start of string
 http        # match 'http'
 s?          # 's' if it exists is okay
 :\/\/       # match '://'
 ([^\/]+\.)? # match any non '/' chars followed by a '.' (if they exist)
 reddit\.com # match 'reddit.com'
 (\/|$)      # match '/' or the end of the string
/i           # match case-insenitive
```

Comment: +1 for the in-depth explanation of the regular expression. Very helpful.

Answer (score 14):

Close your `if` paren...

Comment: :) Everybody makes mistakes like that. Use something that'll give you errors (like Firebug), because staring at a silently failing JavaScript page is a PITA.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using an alternative to RegEx by looking for the domain in the referrer

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('reddit.com') >= 0) { alert('They came from Reddit.com'); }
```

EDIT: As thekingoftruth points out that doesn't work if reddit.com is included in an URL parameter so I've extended it a little. I've also added toLowerCase() as I spotted that in the RegExp above.

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('?') > 0){
    if (document.referrer.substring(0,document.referrer.indexOf('?')).toLowerCase().indexOf('reddit.com') >= 0){
    alert('They came from Reddit');
    }
} else {
    if (document.referrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('reddit.com') > 0){
            alert('They came from Reddit');
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue is if the referrer contains a sub-url within it as a query parameter, say.

Comment: Fair point thekingoftruth. I suppose I could do a check for a ? and look before that. I've also added a toLowerCase().

I'm just a little sad (if not surprised) that the one line solution isn't anymore :-)

Comment: I hear you. Javascript really makes it hard to have compact one-liners. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ref.match(new RegExp("^http://(www\\.)?reddit\\.com/", "i"))
```

Or:

```
ref.match(/^http:\/\/(www\.)?reddit\.com\//i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this, wouldn't it be a lesser and simply way?

```
  var referral= document.refferer;
   If(referral.includes("www.reddit.com"){
  alert("you came from reddit");
   }
     else{
    alert("you didn't come from reddit");
       {
```

Answer (score -4):

Use var ref = document.referer;
// ONE R instead of TWO

Comment: This matches exactly what I was looking for; the referer in the header.