# Hide div after user enters any section of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a full `image div` that fadeouts when the user enters to the site on **homepage**.

I want to hide that full image animation if the **user enters** to any section **(bio, gallery) and comes back to home.**

I tried using a cookie like this:

```
if (jQuery.cookie('hasVisited')) {

} else {
jQuery.cookie('hasVisitied', 'true');
    jQuery('#home-image').hide();
}
```

But the problem is that this hides the `image` for always if the user enters to the page again, Not just to any section.

How can I point to hide the `#home-image` if the user come from subpages of the website.

Let me know if i'm not clear with the question!

This would be the events:

1. User visits website and there is a `full screen image` fadeout animation on home
2. He enters to `biography` section and then comes back to `homepage` **without having to see the `full screen image` animation.**
3. Hours later he decides to visit the website again and on homepage he sees the `full screen image` fadeout animation.

Comment: Your not exactly clear...give us a run through of events if you were a user.

Comment: Quick tip: you can write `$(` instead of `jQuery(`. Much simpler and shorter ;)

Comment: Relevance to `php` tag?

Comment: @VIDesignz I updated my question with an hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Did you set an expiration for the cookie?

Comment: No, it's not a matter of how many minutes or hours ago the user visited the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using cookies, you could end links back to your home page with something like #returning. So, links to your home page may looks like `./#returning` or `www.yoursite.com#returning`.

From there, you can use JavaScript's `window.location.hash` to determine whether or not the user is returning to your home page or not. It should return something like `#returning`.

So, linking to your home page:

```
<a href="./#returning>Home</a>
```

And your JavaScript on the home page:

```
if(window.location.hash === "#returning")
    $('#home-image').hide();
```

Otherwise, if you want to stick with the cookie method, try to find a way to delete the cookies upon the user leaving your site, although that would be a bit more difficult.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Just joined, so I didn't know I could do that. Good to know for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to only add the cookie when they're on of the alternate pages. You can either check the `location.pathname` via javascript, or only include/execute this script on those pages.

As long as the home page doesn't trigger the cookie, it should work

Comment: I don't get it. If I put the cookie on the other pages, he will not see the `image` on `Home`. But also if he visits the `Home` after some hours he will not see the `image` because he has already opened the other sections.

Comment: Then can you clarify in which scenarios the user should not see it? If you specifically need to hide it when they come from a different subpage, you can check the referrer header. Cookies typically last a while unless you customize the expires value

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for... hide the `image` then they come from subpages of the site! What would be the way to do this?

Comment: You can try comparing the `document.referrer` which is the url of the page that sent them. If it matches your domain or certain pages/folders then you can hide the image. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031362/checking-the-referrer