# Prevent cURL requests from my website

Tags: javascript, php, curl, screen-scraping

I have a website containing a large DB of products and prices.
I am being constantly cURLed for prices.

I thought of preventing it with a `<noscript>` tag but all I can do with this is hide the content, bots would still be able to scrape my content.

Is there  a way of running a JS test to see if js is disabled (to detect bots) and redirect these requests, maybe in a blacklist.

Will doing so block google from going through my website?

Comment: You can deny requests without an `userAgent` (but with cURL you can bypass this) or whitelist Google, Facebook, Twitter bots `userAgent` etc..

Comment: As long as the data is public, there really is no easy automated solution. The bots can always be rewritten to bypass your checks.

Comment: Why don't use htaccess to block bots by IP or location ?

Comment: you may probably want to use some authentication or track users with cookies

Comment: @VincentDecaux they just change their IP, it won't last long

Comment: In case of form(s) you can use captcha

Comment: Do you have any idea how "Incapsula" does this? trying to use cURL on "myanimelist.net" and gets a weird incapsula error.

Answer (score 1):

Since CURL is just an html request your server can't differentiate unless you limit certain urls' access or check for referrer url's and implement a filter for anything not referred locally. An example of how to build a check can be found here:

[Checking the referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031362/checking-the-referrer)

Comment: I can use any referer I want when sending a request. It's simply another header

Comment: I didn't say it would be impossible to spoof, I said it was a viable option and one of the few if not only ways to filter an incoming http request. Not sure why people down vote something that is valid and helpful advice. Instead of down voting, why not post a better solution.

Comment: Well the answer is just not correct. The correct answer is: you can not.

Comment: There *is* a way to do it, this just isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

You can block unspoofed `cURL` requests in php by checking the `User Agent`. As far as I know none of the search engine crawlers have curl in their user user agent string, so this shouldn't block them.

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'curl') !== false) {
    http_response_code(403); //FORBIDDEN
    exit;
}
```

Note that changing the `User Agent` string of a `cURL` request is trivial, so someone could easily bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a block list and block the ips from accessing the content, all headers including referrer and user agent can be set in curl very easily with the simple following code

```
$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.yoursite.com?data=anydata');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.yoursite.com');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

the above will make the curl request look like a normal connection from a browser using firefox.