# Stop someone grabbing my data using php curl or something?

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

There's a lots of websites out there, sharing grabber scripts. I meant just install a script and you can have someones whole data. My personal site is based on Youtube API3 and our developer designed it to download videos from youtube.

But, the problem is, If someone wrote another script to stole my data, I mean grab my site's content with php curl or something, how can I stop him?

I can detect and block a single IP, but that's not the best solution. Please help me with some code's what we can put directly into our .htaccess file or somewhere to stop grabbing our content.

Comment: CURL, Firefox, IE.. all are clients, which are designed to grab content, which you are providing.. some of them to store, some of them to display. Blocking access it's against the basics of serving content.

Only possibility here is to handle such request outside the web server, by some soft, which will detect suspicious activity. I mean on lower, thank web application (server) level.

Comment: But *your* data is actually Youtube's data, since you're using their API to populate your site with their videos.

Comment: Marcus, the fact is they are serving from my side, including html, styles, other images everything. Killing my bandwidth and also a big reason for high cpu usage.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103910/prevent-curl-requests-from-my-website#answer-24104054) 
you can check if user use curl then deny access for this user

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'curl') !== false) {
    http_response_code(403); //FORBIDDEN
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Can use wget or anything else. Can send fake agent headers.. it's not solution, I'm afraid..

Comment: Preventing Curl will be enough for me now. Ahmed Please help me a bit more, I should put it on my .htaccess file ?